# Send parameters to IT Hit WebDAV Server

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

we would like to know if it is possible to send parameters to Webdav server (for example as query string path: http://server:8080/WebDavItHit/Notes.txt?param=value...") using **IT Hit WebDAV Server Library for Java + JS Client**.

We are looking forward to validate individual users using other application, and sending some parameters could be really useful.

We appreciate any way or alternative for doing this with your library.

Answer (score 0):

Some WebDAV clients, such as MS Office will truncate query string when saving a document. So to pass parameters, you will typically do this in file path, for example:

```
https://server/[SessionID1234567890]/path/file.ext
```